# Dynamic className in cjsx

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I am trying to hide a component and update the image in a button when I click said button. I have managed to hide the component by doing the follow:

```
{<MyAwesomeComponent /> unless @state.hide}
```

And I change the state by doing:

```
toggleComponent = ->
  @setState
    hide: !@state.hide

. . . 

<div 
  onClick={@toggleComponent}>
  <img 
    src="img/interface/icon-chevron-left.png"
    className={if @hide then "hidden"}/>
</div>
```

Unfortunatelly the {if @hide then "hidden"} doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hide property is set on `@state`, not on the component instance.

```
if @state.hide then "hidden"
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks :)